# What is the request timeout for management api from Devconnect

Tags: timeout, apigee

is there recommended value for request timeout for management api of apigee edge when using from Devconnect.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on two factors

1. User experience for the particular use case
2. Network latency between frontend ( DevConnect server) and backend (Management Server)

My personal favorite is about 20 seconds for a workable web interface.

Comment: If management server max timeout is 60 secs, is it not worth to wait for devconnect till 60 secs rather than closing connecting on 20 sec.?

Comment: For completing a particular call your chance of success is high if you wait for the entire 60 seconds before timing out. But another key question is that, is the user experience acceptable when asked to wait for 60 seconds?  If the answer is yes - then set the time out at 60 seconds.